# Fast GCC build for regression testing

Tags: c++, gcc, build, makefile

I am trying to find bad C++ commit in gcc48 with `git bisect`.
For every commit I do:

```
make distclean
./configure    
nice make -j24 bootstrap
```

This is on the box with 24 cpu.
I suspect that this is sub-optimal and `make` does a lot of extra stuff (like other languages for example).  How can I disable all optional stuff that I don't need for C++ testing? How can I speed up gcc build?

**EDIT**
I was able to reduce build time from 30min to 2min with:

```
git reset --hard &&
rm -rf B/  &&  mkdir B/  &&  cd B/ &&
~/gcc.git/configure  --enable-languages=c,c++  --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --prefix=$HOME/I &&
nice make -j22  &&
make install
```

Comment: Unless your makefiles are screwed up (well, it's a distinct possibility with makefiles...) the time passed in the make command should be very small compared to that of recompiling the whole application. For faster build systems, investigate Ninja (and perhaps CMakefiles which can now produce Ninja files in beta).

Answer (score 1):

There once was a project called compilercache that could be of use. Personnally, I haven't ever tried it or even considered to use it, but from what I read it could be just what you are looking for here.

A quick google search returned this [website](http://www.erikyyy.de/compilercache/).

Comment: It seems the project was abandonned (last update 2006 ?). An up-to-date an otherwise similar project is [CCache](http://ccache.samba.org/), I have been using it intensively at work for years and it's really smooth... and maintained.